# Triple Boot Win7pro/Win7basic and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 14.04, windows-7

I'm looking to triple boot my eeepc 1000he with Win7 and Ubuntu!

I have win7 pro on one partition, win7 basic on another, and i'm thinking
of creating a new partition (obviously) for Ubuntu.

Can this be done without messing my win7's? If so how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How much RAM does your EeePC have? If it has only 1GB of RAM, then your overall hardware specifications are weak for running Ubuntu 14.04, although it can be done. See [How to know which Ubuntu is right for my hardware?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-to-know-which-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware).

Comment: Are both Windows in primary partitions? Ubuntu can be in logical partitions inside an extended partition. Do not use Windows to create partitions as if it converts to dynamic partition then it will not work with Linux. But do use Windows to shrink a NTFS partition to make room for Ubuntu and reboot so it can run chkdsk. And only use Something Else to install, not any auto options which may erase one or the other install.

Comment: It has 2gb @karel

Comment: @oldfred I get the first part, but what do you mean by "...use Something Else..."? I was thinking: 1st:Partition 2nd:Ububtu livecd->install...

Comment: Something Else is the manual install option on the first screen. Then you either create or reuse partitions yourself, choose mount & choose format. Are not first two or three partitions Windows?

Comment: @oldfred Oh... right! Yes, three win partitions. Well, thanks guys, i'll give it a try...